# SublimeText3 plugin on_modified api implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm trying to develop some plugin for **SublimeText3**.

The plugin is supposed to behave on every modification of the text, so looking at the api

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html

`on_modified_async(view)` is the one to use I guessed.

so the code goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sublime, sublime_plugin, socket

class testCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
            self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World1!")
            self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World2!")
            def on_modified_async(self, view):
                self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World3!")
```

This code works as intended for Hello, world 1&2, but 3 is never fired.

I'm quite new to both SublimeText plugin and python3.3 development.
What do I miss? Thank you.
//
EDIT

```
 MESSAGE = self.view.substr(0,50)
TypeError: substr() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

it looks I gave 2 positional arguments, not 3.

---

I've got an error :AttributeError: 'MyEventListener' object has no attribute 'view'......What is wrong with my code(Edited)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, socket

class testCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):  
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World1!")

class MyEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified_async(self,view):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World2!")
```

--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 279, in on_modified_async
    callback.on_modified_async(v)
  File "/Users/ken/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/test/test.py", line 11, in on_modified_async
    self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World2!")
AttributeError: 'MyEventListener' object has no attribute 'view'
```

---

This is the working code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, socket

class MarkdownLiveCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):  
        tcp(self.view)

class MyEventListener1(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified_async(self, view):
        tcp(view)

def tcp(view):
        #do the job
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the docs, you need to create a class extending `sublime_plugin.EventListener` and define your `on_modified_async` method there - defining it in the `run` method of a `TextCommand` doesn't actually do anything. Something like this:

```
class MyEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified_async(self, view):
        edit = view.begin_edit()
        view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World2!")
        view.end_edit(edit)
```

Regarding the error with the `substr` method, `view.substr` takes a `sublime.Region` instance, not two points:

```
message = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, 50))
```

The error message can be a bit confusing because the first argument is the view itself; passing two explicit arguments results in the method being called with three arguments.

Comment: Thank you. sublime.Region(0, 50) issue is resolved; however, I've got an error :AttributeError: 'MyEventListener' object has no attribute 'view'......What is wrong with my code(Edited).

Comment: @KenOKABE The `EventListener` class doesn't have an attribute for the view, but it gets passed to the function. So just use `view` instead of `self.view`.

Comment: Ok, I've got the idea, thanks a lot.Perhaps, the code presented above still got some error, but my other version works fine.

Comment: In Sublime Text 3, apparently you cannot get a view edit object here like this, you have to run a separate command. Other than that, I managed to get on_modified_async to work. Yay!

Comment: What would be that command? To get the view edit object in ST3 I mean.